# difference between environment variables and parsing command line options?

Tags: environment-variables, options

Am I wrong in assuming that both environment variables serve similar purposes - to modify default behaviour of a program from the shell? When writing a program in C, for example, if I am faced with two choices - using something like `getenv()` to see if environment variables for example have been set or `getopt()` to check if an equivalent option has been set, which one should I prefer?

Edit: The `java` JRE launcher uses the `export CLASSPATH=...` environment variable and also has an option called `-cp...` which basically does the same thing. Is there any preference for this kind of thing?

Comment: I would actually do both. If `-i` is given then use that to modify case. If `-i` is not on the command line, check for the env variable and use it. Last option is to use the default built into the program.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the example in my edit to something more practical.